# Copy non-directory over directory and vv

Tags: linux, cp

How can I avoid the following types of errors, and force the
operation to occur?:

```
  /bin/cp: cannot overwrite directory `./foo' with non-directory
  /bin/cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./usr/share/doc' with directory `/usr/share/doc'
```

To backup a partition, I want to copy a new version of a
directory onto an old version, to make them identical, with the
command:

```
/bin/cp -xau --remove-destination  / .
```

The destination directory is in a ZFS filesystem that is being
regularly snapshotted.  Relatively few files (or directories)
change.

That is why I don't want to just delete the whole
destination directory -- that will make the snapshot needlessly
large.

This is in Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix and should be on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: An error quiet strange. Are you sure that both the `./usr/share/doc` and `/usr/share/doc` is a directories?

Comment: 1. Sorry, any future similar questions will go to unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: 2. Yes that was a copy and paste of the message.   The ./usr/share/doc I wanted to overwrite was a link.  I also created small test cases and got the same errors.  If you're wondering what was going on:  earlier I ran out of space on the root partition and so moved /usr/share/doc somewhere else and linked it.  Later I recovered some space, was able to bring /usr/share/doc back to the root partition, and then wanted the latest backup snapshot to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work better (but not perfectly):

```
tar cf /mytmp/root.tar --one-file-system / 
cd /backup/root
tar xvf /mytmp/root.tar --keep-newer-files
```

Note that this works better when /mytmp is not in the root
partition. :-)

The output from the 2nd tar command was 700K lines.  I captured
it inside an emacs buffer and searched it for error messages.
There were two problems with not wanting to replace directories
with links, which I handled manually.